# How to highlight all the buttons with the same index value with hover in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have JavaScript object data from a JSON file where some entries have a `spanid` (number) and some entries don't. I have written a React code to highlight the buttons  which have a `spanid` on hover but I want to highlight all the buttons with the same index i.e. `spanid` when one button with the same `spanid` is hovered. The buttons without `spanid` are not highlighted. Can anyone suggest me a way to highlight or change the background color of all the buttons with the same `spanid` or index when any button with the same `spanid` is hovered through?

App.css

```css
.example_c {
  color: #494949 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #494949 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:120px;
  }

.example_c:hover {
  background: #556bce;
  color: white !important;
}

.example_d {
  color: #494949 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #494949 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:120px;
  }
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Records from "./records.json";
class Relation extends React.Component {


  render () {
     const tokens_to_render = [];
     const input_tokens = Records;

     var cntr = 0;

     input_tokens.forEach(tk => {
         const span = tk['spanid'];
         if (!tk['spanid']) {
             tokens_to_render.push(
                 <button key={cntr} index={tk['spanid']} className='example_d'> 
                     {tk['token_text']} 
                </button>
            )
            cntr = cntr + 1;
         } else {
  
            tokens_to_render.push(
                <button key={cntr} index={tk['spanid']} className='example_c' > 
                    {tk['token_text']} 
                </button>
            )
            cntr = cntr + 1;
         }
    });
  
    return (
        <div className="control-box">
           {tokens_to_render}
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Relation;
```

Comment: As this really appears to be about the rendered HTML and how to highlight with CSS or some other way, perhaps you can post a small example of that rendered HTML?  OR better make this a functional running example snippet using this example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [`mouseover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event) and [`mouseout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) events to set a state for the `spanid` being hovered. You can then evaluate the equality of this state with the other buttons when re-rendering to indicate those should be indicated in someway:

```js
const Records = [
  {
    spanid: 'foo',
    token_text: 'Same',
  },
  {
    spanid: 'bar',
    token_text: 'Not same',
  },
  {
    spanid: 'foo',
    token_text: 'Same foo',
  },
  {
    token_text: 'Baz',
  },
];

class Relation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hovered: null,
    };
    
    this.unsetHover = this.unsetHover.bind(this);
  }
  
  setHover(id) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({ hovered: id });
    }
  }
  
  unsetHover() {
    this.setState({ hovered: null });
  }
 
  render () {
     const tokens_to_render = [];
     const input_tokens = Records;

     var cntr = 0;

     input_tokens.forEach(tk => {
         const span = tk['spanid'];
         if (!tk['spanid']) {
             tokens_to_render.push(
                 <button key={cntr} index={tk['spanid']} className='example_d'> 
                     {tk['token_text']} 
                </button>
            )
            cntr = cntr + 1;
         } else {
  
            tokens_to_render.push(
                <button
                  key={cntr}
                  index={tk['spanid']}
                  className={`example_c ${tk.spanid === this.state.hovered && 'example_c-hovered'}`}
                  onMouseOver={this.setHover(tk.spanid)}
                  onMouseOut={this.unsetHover}
                > 
                    {tk['token_text']} 
                </button>
            )
            cntr = cntr + 1;
         }
    });
  
    return (
        <div className="control-box">
           {tokens_to_render}
        </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<Relation/>);
```

```css
.example_c {
  color: #494949 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #494949 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:120px;
  }

.example_c-hovered,
.example_c:hover {
  background: #556bce;
  color: white !important;
}

.example_d {
  color: #494949 !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #494949 !important;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  width:120px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The spanids are basically numbers and if I want to club the consecutive buttons with the same spanid into only one button with the tesxts joined by space, how can I do that?

Comment: Consider using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) or similar to merge text with the same ID when creating the list of buttons.

Comment: Record= [ 
    {
       "token_text": "Canis",
        "spanid": 1
    },
    {
       "token_text": "Familiaris",
        "spanid": 1
    },
    {
       "token_text": "is"
    },
    {
        "token_text": "the"
    },
    {
      "token_text": "scientific"
    },
    {
        "token_text": "name"
    },
    {
       "token_text": "of"
    },
    {
       "token_text": "dog",
        "spanid": 2
    },
    {
       "tkid": 9,
        "token_text": "."
    }]
How can I reduce this data to club the words with same spanid in one button using the above code?

Comment: Thanks, if you have time, pleae let me know how to do this. The order of the words is messed up when I use reduce.